# Cannot use import statement outside a module when importing a const from another js file

Tags: javascript

I am developing a chrome extension.

One of my js files contains a `const` object.

I tried to import this from another `js` file in the same directory.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

In my `attributes.js`

```
export const key_attributes = {
    'GK': ['Aerial', 'Agility', 'Handling', 'Reflexes'],
}
```

I have the above

In `table.js`, I have

```
import { key_attributes } from './attributes'
```

This gives me

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

Any help?

Comment: It's telling you that `table.js` is not a module

Comment: Try `type="module"` on the `<script>` tag?

Comment: I have tried that it is working at my end, Could you please close and restart your editor, or  If your using npm packages, then delete the node_modules folder and try to do npm install again,  may be it is not getting import statement